# negative roots of a squared term in Matlab

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, roots, matlab, linear-programming

I have an array of numbers, $B$, that can be written as $B = A^2$, where $A$ is also an array of numbers consisting of positive and negative numbers.

If I take the square root of $B$ in MatLab using $C = \sqrt{B}$ I will only get the positive values of $A$. Is there a way to get the negative values of $A$?

Thinking about it, it is probably impossible to do this since Matlab would have to guess which values are negative. Am I right?

Comment: I do not completely understand what you are looking for, can you give us an example?

Comment: edited the question. tanx.

Comment: If I understand you correctly: No, nobody can do that (not even matlab). If you only know the value $a = x^2$ it is not possible to find out whether $x$ has been $x=-\sqrt{a}$ or $x=\sqrt{a}$ in the first place.

Comment: The inverse function of $B = A^2$, often defined as $\pm\sqrt{B}$, is [non-injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) for the real numbers and thus is [not invertible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Example:_squaring_and_square_root_functions). However, if the domain is restricted to the nonnegative reals, i.e., you know that $A \ge 0$, then $B = A^2$ is invertible and $A = \small{+}\sqrt{B}$.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I know what you are asking, but if $B$ is some matrix, `sqrt(B)` will do the trick; `sqrt(B)` will accept negative values and give you a complex number back. If you are looking to do [square roots of complex numbers](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/50738-how-to-compute-sqrt-of-complex-number), then you will need to use polar coordinates.

**EDIT** After your edit, what you are looking for is both the negative and positive solutions to $y = x^2$, i.e. $y = \pm \sqrt{x}$. There is not an immediate way to do so in matlab, that I know of. What you could do is just declare a new matrix `D = -sqrt(B)`. You could use conditional loops, but that is probably more pain than it is worth. After declaring matrix `D`, the $(i,j)$-entry would be the opposite sign of the $(i,j)$-entry in `sqrt(B)`. From there, if you *really* wanted both answers in one matrix, you could define a new $n \times n \times 2$ array. Of which the $n \times n \times 1$ entry is `sqrt(B)` and the $n \times n \times 2$ entry is `-sqrt(B)`.

Also, as the comment points out, there is no way to know for certain that if $y = x^2$, then $x$ was the negative/positive solution (I guess if someone trivially told you). Otherwise, we just say it is *either* $-\sqrt{y}$ or $\sqrt{y}$